# Foreign Key SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys

i am creating a student database in sql server 2005 but it gives me error regarding foreign keys please check whats the problem in it.

```
 CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
STUDENT_REGNO  INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
STUDENT_FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_LASTNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_FATHER_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_EMAIL VARCHAR(20),
STUDENT_MOBILE_NO VARCHAR(15),
STUDENT_PHONE_NO VARCHAR(15),
STUDENT_ADDRESS VARCHAR (40),
DEPARTMENT_ID INT   CONSTRAINT DEP_1 FOREIGN KEY
 REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_ID),
ACADEMIC_ID INT CONSTRAINT ACDEMIC FOREIGN KEY
REFERENCES ACADEMIC(ACADEMIC_ID),
CLASS_NAME VARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT CLASS_1 FOREIGN KEY 
REFERENCES CLASS(CLASS_NAME)
)
CREATE TABLE FACULTY
(
FACULTY_ID INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FACULTY_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FACULTY_FATHER_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
FACULTY_EMAIL VARCHAR(20),
FACULTY_ADDRESS VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
FACULTY_MOBILE_NO VARCHAR(30),
FACULTY_PHONE_NO VARCHAR(20),
FACULTY_QUALIFICATION VARCHAR(20),
DEPARTMENT_ID INT CONSTRAINT DEPARTEMNT_2 FOREIGN KEY 
REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_ID),
ACADEMIC_ID INT CONSTRAINT ACADEMIC_1 FOREIGN KEY
REFERENCES ACADEMIC(ACADEMIC_ID)
)
CREATE TABLE USER1
(
USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
USER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
USER_TYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

)
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(
DEPARTMENT_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DEAPRTMENT_OFFICE_NO VARCHAR(20),
)
CREATE TABLE CLASS
(
CLASS_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CLASS_STRENGTH INT NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE ANNOUNCMENT
(
ANNOUNCMENT_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ANNOUNCMENT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
ANNOUNCMENT_TITLE VARCHAR(45)
)
CREATE TABLE FORUM
(
FORUM_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FORUM_NAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
FORUM_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(333),
FORUM_DISCUSSION VARCHAR(22),
POSTED_BY VARCHAR(34)
)
CREATE TABLE GRADE
(
LETTER_GRADE CHAR NOT NULL ,
PERCENTAGE FLOAT NOT NULL,
STUDENT_REGNO int CONSTRAINT STUDENT_5 FOREIGN KEY(STUDENT)
REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_REGNO),
COURSE_ID int CONSTRAINT COURSE_1 FOREIGN KEY(COURSE)
REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_ID)
)
CREATE TABLE COURSE
(
COURSE_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
COURSE_CREDIT_HR INT NOT NULL,
COURSE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(99),
)
CREATE TABLE TERM
(
TERM_START_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
TERM_END_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
student_regno int CONSTRAINT STUDENT_2 FOREIGN KEY(STUDENT)
REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_REGNO)
)
CREATE TABLE PREVIOUS_ACADEMIC_INFO
(
ACADEMIC_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DEGREE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
CERTIFICATION VARCHAR(30),
DURATION DATETIME
)
CREATE TABLE TEACHER_COURSE
(
AREA_OF_SPECILIZATION VARCHAR(30),
faculty_id int CONSTRAINT FACULTY_1 FOREIGN KEY(FACULTY)
REFERENCES FACULTY(FACULTY_ID)
)
```

and first error is

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
>   Foreign key 'STUDENT_5' references
>   invalid column 'STUDENT' in
>   referencing table 'GRADE'.
>   Msg 1750,  Level 16, State 0, Line 65
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors

Comment: Error details would be helpful.

Comment: Yyou want people to read your code, but you don't post the error? how is that reasonable?

Comment: @Jay@Mitch Wheat :error mentioned..... just tell me whether foreign keys are declared correctly or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE GRADE
(
LETTER_GRADE CHAR NOT NULL ,
PERCENTAGE FLOAT NOT NULL,
STUDENT_REGNO int CONSTRAINT STUDENT_5 FOREIGN KEY(STUDENT) REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_REGNO),
COURSE_ID int CONSTRAINT COURSE_1 FOREIGN KEY(COURSE)
REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_ID)
)
```

Should be

```
CREATE TABLE GRADE
(
LETTER_GRADE CHAR NOT NULL ,
PERCENTAGE FLOAT NOT NULL,
STUDENT_REGNO int CONSTRAINT STUDENT_5 FOREIGN KEY(STUDENT_REGNO) REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_REGNO),
COURSE_ID int CONSTRAINT COURSE_1 FOREIGN KEY(COURSE_ID) REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_ID)
)
```

And so on. Though it is not required and you can just do

```
CREATE TABLE GRADE
(
LETTER_GRADE CHAR NOT NULL ,
PERCENTAGE FLOAT NOT NULL,
STUDENT_REGNO int CONSTRAINT STUDENT_5 REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_REGNO),
COURSE_ID int CONSTRAINT COURSE_1 REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_ID)
)
```

Comment: Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Foreign key 'DEP_1' references invalid table 'DEPARTMENT'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.